# Custom text on jquery ui datepicker event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm receiving an array from a database with some dates and a description for each day.
I wish to display a jquery datepicker calendar where the specified dates are displayed with a custom css class.
Besides that the user should be able to click on the specific date and get the description displayed in a different div element.

The first part with the css class is working, but I can't get the description to display.
This is what I have so far:

```
var Event = function(text, className) {
    this.text = text;
    this.className = className;
};

var events = {};
events[new Date("09/18/2012")] = new Event("description 1", "pink");
events[new Date("09/19/2012")] = new Event("description 2", "green");

$("#minical").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var event = events[date];
        if (event) {
            return [true, event.className, event.text];
        }
        else {
            return [true, '', ''];
        }
    },
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 


    },
    minDate: "-3Y",
    maxDate: "+3Y",
    showButtonPanel: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    "showButtonPanel": true
});

<style>
.pink > a { 
    background-color: pink !important;
    background-image:none !important;
}

.green > a { 
    background-color: green !important;
    background-image: none !important;
}
</style>
```

Thx in advance

Comment: it's working for me.. at least in chrome http://jsfiddle.net/6GNwH/

Comment: Yeah, I forgot an important part :)
I wanted the description to be displayed with an onSelect event in another div with id="description"

My bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure if i understand your needs, but if I understand it correct, you want to display the desciption of the selected date/event in another div.

your `onSelect` event could be like this:

```
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
     var event = events[new Date(dateText)];
     $("#description").html(event.text);
}
```

Comment: Cool. This is excactly what I wanted :)
I read my own post and I can see it's confusing. You got it right though. Thx