# Jquery datepicker language file breaks object

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

After implementing the datepicker from [Custom text on jquery ui datepicker event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12500841/custom-text-on-jquery-ui-datepicker-event) I wish to include language support for my users.

As a matter of fact I had already and it worked perfectly - until I inserted the onSelect function from the thread above.

Now I get a console error saying: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'event.text')

As soon as I remove my language file, the error is gone and the calendar is back to plain english

I tried with several different language files - all with same result

I updated the previous fiddle and added a language file as a resource. Removing this will make the code work http://jsfiddle.net/6GNwH/7/

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the datepicker is returning a culture specific string to the onSelect event. You could change the onselect to use this method:

```
   var myDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
```

to get the current date.

the new eventhandler looks like this then:

```
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        var myDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        var event = events[myDate];
        $("#description").html(event.text);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your collection events has following items

("09/18/2012") but in your code you use other format of date 18-09-2012.

You got error because your collection does not contain this date.

Solution: use the same format of date in event collection and in datapicker(dataformat can be set via options $( ".selector" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" }); )